# Flutter locking one second ui when i use ScrollController listener

Tags: flutter, provider

in my application i used listener for `ScrollConteroller` to do some another actions into that, for example:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _scrollController = ScrollController();

  _scrollController.addListener(() {
    switch (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection) {
      case ScrollDirection.forward:
        Provider.of<NewMediaFabButtonVisibility>(context, listen: false).changeNewMediaFabButton(visible: true);
        Provider.of<ScreenToolsVisibility>(context, listen: false).changeScreenToolsVisibility(hide: false);
        break;
      case ScrollDirection.reverse:
        Provider.of<NewMediaFabButtonVisibility>(context, listen: false).changeNewMediaFabButton(visible: false);
        Provider.of<ScreenToolsVisibility>(context, listen: false).changeScreenToolsVisibility(hide: true);
        break;
      case ScrollDirection.idle:
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

when i scrolling `ListView` top or bottom this listener work as well but that cause of locking my screen for 1 second, and after that scrolling listview work, is any another solution to fix this problem?

when i commented `Providers` implementations scrolling listview work as well

Comment: Well, since you said it happens only when you call these methods and they are your custom code and you have not posted them, what do you expect us to do?

Comment: @nvoigt i hiding another widgets on scrolling `listview`, i think i should use streams